# Initializing the Command Invoker in Command Pattern

Tags: design-patterns

In the command pattern There is a command invoker which is used to handle all the commands that come in. In my case all the commands should be coming in to a single object of this invoker, because I am managing the queuing and thread pool in the invoker.  Is it a good idea to make the invoker a Singleton class?

Comment: Are you using anything on your invoker that is not a singleton or that doesn't have the same lifespan (ex : ORM Session) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would vote against making it a Singleton. It might appear attractive at first but will soon prove more problematic than it's worth.

If you keep it as an instance, you can ensure that it's shared among those that need it by constructor/method injection. This means your design will be more testable and will allow you to use an IoC container in the future.

This might appear as over-engineering at this point but, IMHO, incorporating SOLID principles early pays a healthy dividend later.

Comment: Thanks David, I wanted to go with the best possible design.